# ACORD AL3 - What's the deal with "?"s

Tags: standards

We're writing a parser for ACORD AL3. Read AL3 coming in, write AL3 going out. Nice and simple.

As of right now, it is 99% solid. The only thing that's driving me nuts is the use of "?"s in the ACORD AL3 standard. It appears that they are used as placeholders for fields that do not have values in the message. HOWEVER, that's not the only rule for it, because if it was, the AL3 I'm currently generating would look that the sample files I'm trying to have it match.

So if anyone here knows anything about the rules around AL3 "?"s, that would be great. I've been pouring over the Data Dictionary and the other documentation from ACORD, and I'm seeing nothing to indicate which fields get it, and which ones don't.

Also, if the "?"s are not required for AL3 processing to begin with, that would also be great to know, because then I could just stop worrying about the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

In the ACORD AL3 standard, from what I recall, if you use a "?" in one of the fields, this tells the receiving system to not overwrite (with blanks) the target field in the user's management system.

Answer (score 0):

There may be individual elements in a group that are valid, but the sender 
cannot send them for some reason.  The solution is to fill that data element with questions marks (?????)  The receiving system will recognize this and not update that field on their system.

Answer (score 0):

In ACORD Al3 "?" means there is not any data in that specific element but that element is much important to maintain the hierarchy. But there is one thing, Coverage groups and Transaction groups will not contains any question mark. that does not means these are not important even these are very much important in Al3 files. But that above mentioned description  applies for data group.
Secondly number of question marks in element describe its length.

If anyone need more details related to al3 data, don't hesitate to ask.